# How can I remove this steel frame basement window?

Tags: windows

I plan to replace the basement windows and frame. The frame is steel and half part embedded in concrete. Do you guys have an experience with this project?

[image]

The wall is solid brick.

Comment: Are those full bricks or a "thin brick" veneer?

Comment: @Mazura, the frame is rusty and broken on the inside. that is why I plan to replace them.

Comment: Bondo. Paint. Done. Picture of the inside? It's still operable?

Comment: Does it look like this? [Are there any risks in removing these steel basement window frames?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/18515/are-there-any-risks-in-removing-these-steel-basement-window-frames), because I heartily disagree with the comment there that "that frame has to come out. It's too rotted to repair" - ye of little faith. Give me a can of Bondo and *'a place to stand'*....

Answer (score 3):

That appears to be a welded, structural unit. It may be supporting the brick. If so, do not remove it without a plan to replace that support. Install a new window into the steel frame and leave it be. You could probably fill it with spray foam  via some strategically placed holes to improve energy efficiency.

*If the brick is otherwise supported*...

1. Remove the aluminum sashes and glass. I can't tell how that's mounted from my viewpoint. Look for screws or other retainers on the inside. If necessary, get rowdy with it, but protect skin and eyes from glass debris.
2. Using a reciprocating saw, or an angle grinder or circular saw with an abrasive wheel, cut through the center of each side of the frame. If it's a welded unit you won't be able to just tilt each side out--you'll have to make clearance. It may help to cut the long sides *twice*, so that you can remove a section and allow more movement.
3. Cut away or slice all caulk joints. They hold surprisingly well. Use a utility knife or chisel.
4. Gently work the frame segments loose. I would focus on the inside, where presumably you have finish jambs or other covering over the masonry to hide damage.
5. Using cold chisels or abrasive power tools, clean up the opening so it's flat and square.
6. Do any necessary repair of the masonry, such as tuck-pointing deep voids. Minor depressions can be filled with spray foam during installation of the new window.

At all times, seek to preserve the external brickwork. That's difficult to repair, and damage will undermine the quality of your finished work.

Comment: Ah, done this before have we? Cut it, bend it, mangle it, bang on it, w/e just get it TFO. Half way through you'll wish you went with just putting a smaller one in the frame. But once it's done you'll see you'd never forgive yourself for skimping.

Answer (score 1):

If this was my project and I wanted some other type of window I would strip out all the old window panes, pane frames, screens, slides hinges etc ... but leave the main metal frame intact. It is really just too risky and messy to try removing the metal frames that are embedded in the mortar bed.

Custom build your new windows in such manner that they fit inside the existing metal frame and trim out around it on the inside and outside.

Comment: If there's a steel lintel supporting the brick there's no real reason this window can't be cut out. A new window installed properly will not degrade the integrity of the wall. Installing a window inside that frame would dramatically reduce glass size.

Comment: I once had a commercial client that wanted it that way. The owner who did the accounting wanted that. The other owner laughed when we 'miss-measured' and ended up having to remove the frames, which provided 4" more window *on all sides*. People were worried we'd lose the job, except that was the one mistake we made in 5y and it happened to be the correct way to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

That’s a window buck.  Does your foundation come up to the top of the “buck” on both sides.  Most likely it does and that means your foundation was poured around the buck - top, sides, and bottom - obviously.  You usually want to leave the top and sides of that buck in place, when installing an egress window.  If you’re just replacing the glass, buy replacement inserts.