# Removal of old basement windows embedded in concrete

Tags: basement, windows

I have a bunch of old basement windows that has the frame embedded in the concrete that I need to replace. They look different than most people's posts about monarch windows that have a wide frame embedded in concrete. What is the best way to go about upgrading these windows?

Thanks!
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: *"Cut it, bend it, mangle it, bang on it, w/e just get it TFO"* [How can I remove this steel frame basement window?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/251247/how-can-i-remove-this-steel-frame-basement-window)

Answer (score 0):

There are videos on the web that go through removing and replacing them, so I'm not going to repeat it here. Even for a pro it's an ugly brute-force process involving angle grinders, reciprocating saws, cold chisels, big hammers, and big levers.

One trustworthy place you might look for a video would be This Old House's website. At least that way you know the folks doing the job are pros and are demonstrating an approach that will work.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the sliding part of the window.
2. Remove the frame using a chisel. Depending on how deeply embedded each frame is to the concrete, you might need to use an angle grinder to cut the metal and leave part of the metal inside of the concrete.
3. Get a new window in place.
4. Use mortar to set the new frame into the concrete. Then it's the next person's turn a 100 years from now to get a chisel and break through your mortar. Or you could make a wood frame and install smaller basement windows.

Answer (score 0):

Use a "retrofit" window. Bust out the glass and use an angle grinder to cut/grind off all of the frame parts that are *not* embedded in concrete. Then install "retro-fit" windows from the outside, covering the remaining old frame work. Finish by using trim strips on the inside to cover the remaining old interior frame work.

[image]